# Separate staging and production pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-pipelines

I'd like to have separate pipelines for microservices, and also staging and production. It would look like this:

[image]

I'm just starting to setup the `azure-pipelines.yaml` and have this as the trigger for `admin`:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - staging
    - production
  paths:
    include:
    - admin/*

resources:
  - repo: self
```

The issue I'm running into, as you might see right off the bat, is that when I commit to `staging` it is triggering both of the pipelines.

So my question is: is there a way to have one `yaml` for both `staging` and `production` for this microservice or do I need to have two separate `yaml` files?

---

EDIT:

Given these two things, I think what I'm trying to do is unlikely unless I make separate `adminStaging.yaml` and `adminProduction.yaml`:

> You cannot use variables in triggers, as variables are evaluated at runtime (after the trigger has fired).

> If you use templates to author YAML files, then you can only specify triggers in the main YAML file for the pipeline. You cannot specify triggers in the template files.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: Branch-per-environment is an antiquated pattern that doesn't work well with Git or modern thinking around how continuous delivery should be implemented. I'd suggest revisiting your branching strategy and adopting something like GitFlow or GitHubFlow.

Comment: @DanielMann Thanks for the suggestion. reading up on it now.

Comment: Also, without seeing the rest of your pipeline, I'm not convinced that the reason you're getting the production environment built/deployed is because of your `trigger` statement. As coded, your example says that a commit on either of those branches triggers the pipeline, not that it triggers both environments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @Daniel Mann, you should move toward adopting a more modern branching strategy. Gitflow or Trunk-based with release branches is typically what I use:

- [Gitflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow)
- [Trunk based with release branches](https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/branch-for-release/)

They each have their advantages and disadvantages, but either will cover your use-case. You'd you a non-prod branch (**develop or rc/***) and a production branch (**master**). UAT deployments would be triggered off of the non-prod branch(es) and prod releases would be triggered from **master**.

However, to address your question regarding if it's possible to deploy to both UAT and Production, while having a trigger pointed to both branches, yes. You're able to set up your YAML pipelines to be able to, but it's a bit inelegant.

Effectively, what you'd want to do is use either a **condition** or an **if statement** to **selectively run your stages based upon the branch** I've included both in the example below:

```
name: Stackoverflow-Example-Multiple-Triggers
trigger:
    - staging
    - production
stages:
    - ${{ if contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/staging') }}:
      - stage: StageA
        displayName: "Stage A"
        jobs:
          - job: output_message_job_a
            displayName: "Output Message Job"
            pool:
                vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"
            steps:
                - powershell: echo "Hello World!"
                  displayName: "Output Message"
            condition: contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/staging')

    - ${{ if contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/production') }}:
      - stage: StageB
        displayName: "Stage B"
        jobs:
          - job: output_message_job_b
            displayName: "Output Message Job"
            pool:
                vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"
            steps:
                - powershell: echo "Hello World!"
                  displayName: "Output Message"
            condition: contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/production')
```

You'll want to note that the behavior of conditions vs if statements differ:

- **Conditions**: Will display the skipped stages within the pipeline, but not run them.
- **If Statements**: Will skip the interpretation of the YAML that doesn't meet the if statement criteria entirely and won't display within your pipeline execution. This means, **your pipeline will fail** if you attempt to run it on anything other than **staging** or **production** branches.